# How to change attribute of html in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change attribute of a div in angularjs. I know how to do in jquery but not in angular.

html :

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="cont">
        <button ng-click="updateStatus()">TOGGLE ATTRIBUTE </button>
        <div id="test" {{status}}>TEXT </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

js :

```
var angApp = angular.module('test',[]);
angApp.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.status = 'someattr';
    $scope.updateStatus = function() {
        if( $scope.status == 'someattr'){
          $scope.status = '';
        }else{
            $scope.status = 'someattr';
        } 
    };
}])
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gautm5154/5h195302/11/) to work with.

In jquery :

```
 var div = $('#test');
 $('button').on('click',function(){
   if( div.attr('someattr'){
      div.removeAttr('someattr');
   }else{
      div.attr('someattr',true); 
   }
})
```

I want to achive same in angularjs.

**NOTE : I AM NOT TRYING TO ADD DISABLED STATE TO DIV. I JUST WANT TO TOGGLE AN ATTRIBUTE.**

Comment: `ng-click="updateStatus()"` (see the parantheses)

Comment: How can a `div` have `disabled`? What are you tryin to do?

Comment: Please see updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5h195302/7/

Comment: I want to change attribute not html.

Comment: I just used disabled, it can be anything to style css.

Comment: To style CSS dynamically use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle). If you are trying to `hide` use [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) OR [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

Comment: it expects a key,value pair data-disabled="{{status}}" when i try this instead of {{status}} it works check

Comment: i have css which depend upon attribute, please look at jsfiddle. @sourabh

Comment: If you just want to style something differently, you'd normally use ng-class.   It just takes an expression that if true adds the class you want and if false removes it.  http://jsfiddle.net/5h195302/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a directive which uses `.attr` and `.removeAttr` in a `$watch` handler. Here's a modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0eqz1qo1/1/

The directive:

```
.directive('addAttr', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.$watch(attr.addAttr, function(val, prev) {
            if(val)
                elem.attr(val, "");
            if(prev && prev !== val)
                elem.removeAttr(prev);
        });
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
$scope.myVar = 'hello';
...
<div add-attr="myVar"></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div add-attr="myVar" hello></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your specific case (add `disabled` attribute), you have to use `ng-disabled` in order to bind its value to a `$scope` variable.

It makes no sense to use it on a `div`, I'll use a button instead to give you an example:

```
<button ng-click="updateStatus()">TOGGLE ATTRIBUTE </button>
<button id="test" ng-disabled='status'>TEXT</button>
```

see a working example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5h195302/9/)

---

**UPDATE**

To toggle an attribute, yo can use `attr()` and `removeAttr()`:

```
el.attr("disabled", "true");
el.removeAttr("disabled");
```

See a complete example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5h195302/15/)

**NOTE** (thanks to *jme11*): as reported on Angular Dev Guide

> Do not use controllers to:
>   Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM  manipulation.

you should avoid to manipulate the DOM inside the controller.

Comment: I want to add and remove attr when clicked on button.

Comment: how to implement, please give example.

Comment: Have you clicked on the second link?

Comment: While this works, it's not really the right thing to do.  You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM in the controller.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.  (Note the part that reads: Do not use controllers to:  Manipulate DOM).  The correct way to do this is to modify your CSS and use something like ng-class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not implement disable property for any div.But you can hide or show the div using Angular.js.Check the code below.

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="cont">
        <button ng-click="updateStatus()">TOGGLE ATTRIBUTE </button>
        <div id="test" ng-hide="hide-div" >TEXT </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var angApp = angular.module('test',[]);
angApp.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.hide-div = true;
    $scope.updateStatus = function() {
        if( $scope.hide-div == true){
          //do something here
        }else{
            $scope.hide-div = true;
        } 
    };
}])
```

Other option is you can also use ng-class in div and inside those class you can declare `display:none,display:block`

Comment: I am trying to remove or add an attribute.

Comment: @ Gautam :Which type of attribute you want to add/remove.

Comment: some custom attribute.

Comment: @ Gautam : you can use ' ng-attr-id="{{something}}" ' inside the div and pass some value to it (i.e-$scope.something="value").

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an attribute by this way with angularJS. If you inspect your code, you can see that the attribute that you're trying to pass in `div` is `{{status}}`(your expression), **use existing attributes** rather than create your own! For example: `ng-disabled`, `ng-show`, `ng-hide`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line :

```
<div id="test" {{status}}>TEXT </div>
```

with these :

```
<div id="test" someattr="" ng-if="status=='someattr'" >TEXT</div>
<div id="test" ng-if="status==''" >TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really right thing to do. I guess, cannot inject attribute with angularJS. {{status}} is an expression, it's like expression and will evaluate by angularjs while rendering to html. about expression: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression